# Any method similar to CCHMac of iPhone in Android?

Tags: android

I have a problem that I have a code of iPhone to convert something in MD5 and I have to write the same code in Android. But the problem is that there is a method name **CCHMac**, I don't know what is that? what functionality it performed on two string as **key & data**. and Is there any method in JAVA/Android similar to that? Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

**iPhone Code:*

```
secret  = @"e24a6167409288f486a78271cc316c4f";
data = @"/v1/vehicles/get-make-models.json?sort=mpg&to=&filter=category&client-id=10030812&from=convertible";
(NSString  *)signRequestNSString  *)data
{
const  char  *cKey  = [secret  cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];       
const  char  *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
unsigned  char  cHMAC[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgMD5, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData  *HMAC = [[NSData  alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSString  *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedString];
    [HMAC release];
return  hash;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The javax.crypto package contains the HMAC functionality, particularly javax.crypto.Mac.

Comment: How can we use the same in Java/Android? How we call the same and what parameters it needs?